# Linked list structures initialized in functions not being assigned properly

Tags: c, gcc

I'm sure this has been asked before, but I cannot find anything on this website or any other about it after searching for quite awhile.

I''m having trouble getting the values of structures that I'm creating and modifying in a function. The code looks something like:

```
struct node {
  char name[35];
  int employeeID;
  struct node *next;
}

typedef struct node employee;

void insertInOrder(employee *head, employee *curr) {
  if (head == NULL) {
    *curr->next = *head;
    *head = *curr;
  } else {
    if ((head->employeeID<curr->employeeID)&&(curr->employeeID <head->next->employeeID)) {
      *curr->next = *head->next;
      *head->next = *curr;
    } else {
      insertInOrder(head->next, curr);
    }
  }
}

void addEmployee(char name[], employee *head, employee *curr) {
  int id;
  scanf("%d", &id);
  curr = malloc(sizeof(employee));
  strcpy(curr->name, name);
  curr->employeeID = id;
  insertInOrder(head, curr);
}

int main(void) {
  char name[35];
  int quit = 1;
  employee *head, *curr;
  head = NULL;
  printf("Enter data about the books: \n");
  while (quit) {
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", title);
    if (title[0] != '#') {
        addBook(name, head, curr);
    } else {
        quit = 0;
    }
}
```

During my debugging, my code iterates into all of my functions, but once I get back to main after adding all of the data I want, all of the variables are empty. I know it has something to do with the way I'm using or passing pointers, but when I look at the code I keep coming to the logical conclusion that what I have should do what I want. Please, someone point out where my algorithm is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addBook` takes pointers of type `Book` but you are passing pointers of type `Employee`

Edit:

So, first you don't need to do things like `*curr->next = *head`. It should be `curr->next = head`.
Also, `head->next` can be null which is not being checked. Finally, `head` needs to always be pointed at the start of the list.

Edit 2:

Following code should work. `head` always points to the start of the list. In order to do that, we must pass the *address* of the head pointer. We need to do this because we will be modifying the address of `head`.

I've also cleaned up a few things.

```
void insertInOrder(employee **head, employee *curr) {

  if (*head == NULL) {
    // We are inserting the first element
    *head = curr;
  }
  else if ((*head)->next == NULL) {
    // This is the second element. We either insert it in front of head or before head.
    if ((*head)->employeeID < curr->employeeID) {
      (*head)->next = curr;
    }
    else {
      curr->next = *head;
      *head = curr;
      (*head)->next = NULL;
    }
  }

  else {
    // We iterate through the list trying to find the best spot to insert curr.
    employee *temp = *head;
    while (temp->next != NULL) {
        if ((temp->employeeID < curr->employeeID) && (curr->employeeID < temp->next->employeeID))     {
            curr->next = temp->next;
            temp->next = curr;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    // curr has the greatest id so it is inserted at the end
    if (temp->next == NULL)
      temp->next = curr;  
  }
}

void addEmployee(char name[], employee **head) {
  int id;
  printf("Enter id\n");
  scanf("%d", &id);
  employee *curr = malloc(sizeof(employee));
  strcpy(curr->name, name);
  curr->employeeID = id;
  curr->next = NULL;
  insertInOrder(head, curr);
}

int main(void) {
  int quit = 1;
  employee *head = NULL;
  char title[100];
  printf("Enter data about the employees: \n");
  while (quit) {
    scanf("%s", title);
    if (title[0] != '#') 
        addEmployee(title, &head);
    else break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: That was an artifact from old code, thanks for pointing it out. I cut down my actual code to make it simpler and more read able here.

Answer (score 0):

inside the function no need to use *head or *curr ..because -> is made up for pointers only  instead directly use head->left & curr->next

thanks

Comment: Apologies, that was left over from me trying a different possibility. I've changed the code to what I actually have it at.